# Simple if and input doesn't work

Tags: python, python-3.x

I wrote this very simple code, it doesn't work and I can't understand why. I answer 'good' but if part doesn't work!

```
def howdy ():
    p = input("how's it going?")
    if p is "good":
        print("Cheers")
howdy()
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use:

> If p == 'good':

The `==` compares the value of the two. The `Is` keyword checks for identity by comparing  the memory address.

Hope this explains it enough. 
Hannes

Comment: that was a very good point. it worked.thank you very much

Answer (score -1):

have you tried

```
if p == "good":
```

the double equal means the same as.
Also, if you are looking for a helpful free beginner course, try codecademy. They helped me loads learn python

Comment: thanks man, yea it was it.

Comment: No problem, any time